# How to Hide react router parameters and query strings from URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have defined the routes in client.js as below, it works perfectly and i need to pass a JSON, so i tried passing as query parameter.

```
<Router history={appHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path="/user" component={Home}></Route>
</Router>
```

In login component i am changing the route as below,

```
hashHistory.push({
    pathname: '/user',
    query: { JSONResp: JSON.stringify(result.data)}
});
```

Its working fine, i am able to access the query params.

Is there any option to hide this query value from URL and also my JSON response size will be around 2MB is it advisable to pass this data in query parameter.

Comment: You can use PUSH instead of GET method and hide your parameters under PUSH params.

Comment: Also, the parameter's size of GET is limited. So if your data is big, use PUSH

Comment: so i can use as above hashHistory.push?? and how to hide params in push state.. i searched in my sites i didnt find any option

Answer (score 0):

Run `history.pushState(null,null,window.location.href.split('?')[0])`, Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts the browser.